# How to access sub nodes using htmlagilitypack in c# [based on 'from' clause]

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

i have a html as :

```
    <div class="article-listing">
        <div class="media-data">

                             <h4><a href="http://thenextweb.com/media/2012/01/05/24symbols-white-labels-its-platform-to-give-any-organization-its-own-spotify-for-books/">24symbols White-Labels its 'Spotify for Books'</a></h4>
                             <p class="article-meta"><a href="http://thenextweb.com/media/">TNW Media</a> &#8226; <a href="http://thenextweb.com/author/martin/" title="Posts by Martin Bryant" rel="author">Martin Bryant</a>  &#8226; <span class="date" title="1325781355">January 5, 2012</span></a></p>

                             <p>24symbols, the &#8216;Spotify for books&#8217; startup that launched last summer, has been busy developing its service that allows users instant access to a library of books for a fixed fee&#8230;.</p>
                         </div></div>

I am using this xpath code for extracting required information :

    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
                var document = webGet.Load(page);

                var infos = from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='article-listing']//div[@class='media-data']")
                            from link in info.Descendants("a").Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("href"))
                            from content in info.Descendants("p").Where(y => y.HasAttributes != true)
                            from author in info.Descendants("//p[@class='article-meta']//a[@rel='author']").Where(z => z.Attributes.Contains("href"))
                            from date in info.Descendants("//p[@class='article-meta']//span")
                            select new
                                {
                                   LinkURL = link.Attributes["href"].Value,
                                   Text = content.InnerText,
                                   Author = author.InnerText,
                                   Date = date.InnerText
                                };
    lvLinks.DataSource = infos;
                lvLinks.DataBind();
```

I am using list view control to show data in asp page as using `<li> <%# Eval("LinkURL") %> - <%# Eval("Text") %>  - <%# Eval("Author") %> </li>`

But its not working...It is not showing any errors and nor it shows any data on the page..

May be there is some problem with selecting nodes using different 'from' clauses.

Please suggest me
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked encoding of the page you get via `webGet.Load`?
You could possibly start from simple queries like  `document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='article-listing']//div[@class='media-data']")` and increase complexity once you have them working properly.

Comment: @Li0liQ : I have already checked with these...Everything works fine if i go one by one

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue... It was with selection of nodes. One need to use SelectNodes instead of Descendants and also i need to fix the tags passed in SelectNodes() method.
We can use following code and it would work fine.

```
 var infos = from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='article-listing']//div[@class='media-data']")
    from link in info.SelectNodes("h4//a").Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("href"))
    from content in info.SelectNodes("p").Where(y => y.HasAttributes != true)
    from author in info.SelectNodes("p[@class='article-meta']//a[@rel='author']").Where(z => z.Attributes.Contains("href"))
    from date in info.SelectNodes("p[@class='article-meta']//span")

    select new
     {
       LinkURL = link.Attributes["href"].Value,
       Text = content.InnerText,
       Author = author.InnerText,
       Date = date.InnerText
     };
```

lvLinks.DataSource = infos;
  lvLinks.DataBind();

Its working fine...No issue now